# lodash multi param in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, lodash

i have an array and i want to apply some filter on it.
i'm using lodash tovdo this. But i don't know how to add my state values to the condition

```
 this.state = {
        TargetAge : [23 , 101],
        TargetId : [1 ,2],
        TargetName : ['john' , 'bob'],
        TargetStart : '2020-03-19 14:12:30',
        TargetStop: '2020-09-19 14:12:30'

    }
    const myArr = [ {name: "john", age: 23, id: 1, start: '2020-07-19 14:12:30', stop: '2020-08-19 14:12:30'},
                    {name: "john", age: 43,  id: 2, start: '2020-05-19 14:12:30', stop: '2020-09-19 14:12:30'},
                    {name: "jim", age: 101, id: 3, start: '2020-04-19 14:12:30', stop: '2020-06-19 14:12:30'},
                    {name: "bob", age: 67, id: 4, start: '2020-03-19 14:12:30', stop: '2020-07-19 14:12:30'} ];
```

in this case i try with

```
 let tmp = _.filter(myArr, x => x.id == 1 || x.id == 2 );
 console.log(tmp) // god result for id but targetId can be empty

 let tmp = _.filter(myArr, x => x.id == targetId );
     console.log(tmp) // bad result
```

how can i add 0 or X param to filter my array ?

expected output :

```
if this.state.TargetId == [1, 2] && this.state.TargetAge = [23] // in this case other state are empty
 res = [ {name: "john", age: 23, id: 1, start: '2020-07-19 14:12:30', stop: '2020-08-19 14:12:30'}}




if  this.state.TargetStart == '020-04-19 14:12:30'  && this.state.TargetStop = '2020-08-19 14:12:30 // in this case other state are empty 
 res == [ {name: "john", age: 23, id: 1, start: '2020-07-19 14:12:30', stop: '2020-08-19 14:12:30'},
          {name: "jim", age: 101, id: 3, start: '2020-04-19 14:12:30', stop: '2020-06-19 14:12:30'} ]
```

Comment: Can you add your expected output?

Comment: Your code is not clear:
do you mean ` let tmp = _.filter(myArr, x => x.id == this.state.TargetId);` gives a bad result?

Comment: yes my   console.log(tmp) // bad result; tmp is empty

Comment: this.state is dynamic right? You should have same keys in this.state and myArr to filter.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you were close, you just needed to change the functionality slightly.

```
// Your current code:
let tmp = _.filter(myArr, x => x.id == targetId );
     console.log(tmp) // bad result

// What I am pretty sure you want:
let tmp = _.filter(myArr, x => _.includes(this.state.TargetId, x.id));
     console.log(tmp)
```